# How to implement callback function in Typescript (Angular Material)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using *Angular Material Dialog* component, I want to pass an **optional callback function**, and execute if the user click the `OK button`. May I know how to implement it?

```
askUser(customData: any) {
    openDialog() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AskDialog, {
            data: customData
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(isOK=> {
            if (isOK && customData.hasOwnProperty('callback')) {
                // ??? how to execute the "customData.callback"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope I can use the `askUser()` as such:

```
function freeGift(gift: string) { /* ... */ }
function contactPolice(phone: number, email: string) { /* ... */ }

askUser({ // callback
    displayText: 'Are you a superman?',
    callback: freeGift('blue shirt')
});

askUser({ // different callback with different arguments
    displayText: 'Are you a criminal?',
    callback: contactPolice(this.phone, 'police@gmail.com')
});

askUser({ // no callback
    displayText: 'Do not disturb!'
});
```

How to **PASS** the callback into the `customData.callback`, and how to **invoke and execute** the function?

In other words, how to pass a *function* into a "variable", and execute the "variable" later with proper context?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
askUser({ // callback
    displayText: 'Are you a superman?',
    callback: () => freeGift('blue shirt')
});
```

and you would call it like:

```
customData.callback();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved fairly easily, you can execute a function by just using (). Made an example app to elaborate; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8drwks